# how i fix this? confuse install wxpython

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip, wxpython

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\program files\python39\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.

can give me step by step?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using this command to install ?

```
 pip install -U --pre -f https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ wxPython
 pip install -U wxPython
```

https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/README.txt